# Gradle Android not supporting NDK build[gradle migration from 0.12.+ tot 1.1 ]

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-ndk

I recently migrated from Android Studio 0.9+ to 1.+ where I had to change my gradle version from 0.12.+ to 1.1.+ for IDE requirements. My app and jni was running 
My build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "..."
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            moduleName "behagcoder"
            cFlags "-DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFPM_ARM -ffast-math -O3"   // Define some macros
            ldLibs "android", "log"       // Link with these libraries!
            stl "stlport_shared"
        }

    }
    //flavorDimensions "abi"

    productFlavors {
        x86 {
            flavorDimension "x86"
            ndk {
                abiFilter "x86"
            }
        }
        mips {
            ndk {
                abiFilter "mips"
            }
        }
        arm {
            flavorDimension "abi"
            ndk {
                abiFilter "armeabi"
                moduleName "behagcoder"
                cFlags "-DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFPM_ARM -ffast-math -O3"   // Define some macros
                ldLibs "android", "log"       // Link with these libraries!
                stl "stlport_shared"
            }

        }
        armv7 {
            flavorDimension "abi"

            ndk {
                abiFilter "armeabi-v7a"
            }
        }
    }
    sourceSets.main {
        jni.srcDirs = [] // This prevents the auto generation of Android.mk
        jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs'
    }
    task buildNative(type: Exec, description: 'Compile JNI source via NDK') {
        def ndkDir = "/home/shad/Downloads/NDK/android-ndk-r10d"
        commandLine "$ndkDir/ndk-build",
                '-C', file('src/main/jni').absolutePath,
                '-j', Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors(),
                'all',
                'NDK_DEBUG=1'
    }
    task cleanNative(type: Exec, description: 'Clean JNI object files') {
        def ndkDir = "/home/shad/Downloads/NDK/android-ndk-r10d"
        commandLine "$ndkDir/ndk-build",
                '-C', file('src/main/jni').absolutePath,
                'clean'
    }

    clean.dependsOn 'cleanNative'

    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn buildNative
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    ...
}
```

My Android.mk file

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := behagcoder
LOCAL_ARM_MODE  := arm
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := NativeSRLDecoder.cpp bhg/bit.c bhg/decoder.c bhg/fixed.c bhg/frame.c bhg/huffman.c bhg/layer3.c bhg/stream.c bhg/synth.c bhg/timer.c bhg/version.c
LOCAL_CFLAGS    := -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFPM_ARM -ffast-math -O3
# for logging
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog
# for local asset manger
#LOCAL_LDLIBS += -landroid

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Error:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found:

I am new in Android development, I also want to build the app for multiple processor type as x86,mips etc. Thanks in advance

Comment: your configuration looks fine (it could be cleaner if you remove the `ndk{}` block that isn't used here, and use *splits* instead of abiFilters). Your issue certainly comes from something else. What is the error message displayed after "Native method not found" ?

Comment: I have solved the method not found problem, the function was not properly named(silly me:( ). but the problem is in the libs folder only the .so is generated in  armeabi folder. I want the so to be generated on the x86 folder too. Do I need to write separate code for x86?

Comment: Create a file named *Application.mk* and inside, put `APP_ABI:=all` and the ndk will generate your lib for all the supported architectures. You should also add `APP_PLATFORM:=android-17` to ensure the compatibility of your lib with android starting from version 17.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I solved the problem with LOCAL_CFLAGS  := -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFPM_DEFAULT -ffast-math -O3 on Android.mk and APP_ABI := all. I can also change it to  -DFPM_INTEL or  -DFPM_ARM for specific production apk. For  development its ok.